# Loading image in picturebox control repeatedly from local machine

Tags: c#

I have some c# code that gets an image from a webpage then downloads it to my local machine.  This is done in the background 1/sec.  If I leave this running it works fine and my pictures get updated correctly.  These pictures are basically feeds from a camera.  I want to put these pictures into a picturebox or some other control so that I can display the images as if they were a camera feed.  However when I tried doing this I've got errors saying the image is being used so I can not load it into my picturebox. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,

```
 byte[] lnBuffer;
                    byte[] lnFile;

                    HttpWebRequest lxRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

                    lxRequest.Credentials = credentials;
                    using (HttpWebResponse lxResponse = (HttpWebResponse)lxRequest.GetResponse())
                    {

                        using (BinaryReader lxBR = new BinaryReader(lxResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            using (MemoryStream lxMS = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                lnBuffer = lxBR.ReadBytes(1024);
                                while (lnBuffer.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    lxMS.Write(lnBuffer, 0, lnBuffer.Length);
                                    lnBuffer = lxBR.ReadBytes(1024);
                                }
                                lnFile = new byte[(int)lxMS.Length];
                                lxMS.Position = 0;
                                lxMS.Read(lnFile, 0, lnFile.Length);
                                lxMS.Close();
                                lxBR.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        lxResponse.Close();
                    }






                            using (System.IO.FileStream lxFS = new FileStream("images/camppic1.jpg", FileMode.Create))
                            {
                                lxFS.Write(lnFile, 0, lnFile.Length);
                                lxFS.Close();




                            }
```

This is what I use to create the file.  Then in the same method after this code I do this:

image = Image.FromFile("C:\camppic1.jpg");

```
              pictureBox23.Image = image;
```

Comment: Your app could make a [clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.clone.aspx) of the image it downloads and pass that to the picture box before saving to disk. Watch out for memory leaks with what you are doing though, Pictureboxes can be a pain for this

Comment: How would I go about making a clone.  Or feeding the download picture straight to the picturebox?

Comment: Do you really want to store the image as a file? I would recommend to skip the file, both for faster data access, and possibly remove Your current problem... By the way, winforms or...?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the file, then load the file content and copy to a MemoryStream and use [Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx). If you don't need the file, you could skip it and use the MemoryStream directly from the downloading... (Faster since no disc access would be needed.)

Comment: Keep a reference to the old Image when pictureBox.Image is updated, so the Image can be disposed when not used any more.